How should I handle students who are very disengaged in class?
I teach undergraduate mathematics. This semester, I started walking around the classroom while using an iPad to write (to the screen) during lectures. This allows me to notice that a few students are not paying attention and doing all sorts of things on their laptops, sometimes even watching YouTube videos right in front of me. I wonder what the best approach would be to handle such students. I see a few options:

Completely ignore them and focus on students who are engaged and there to study.
Be more direct and ask them to answer questions in class.
Invite them to office hours to understand why they attend class but do not engage. (Note: I do not enforce attendance.)

What would you suggest based on your experience?

"...using an iPad to write during lectures". How does that work, exactly? It sounds like the behavior you don't like. Why don't you require/inforce attendance?

Is this an elementary or an advanced class?

I project my ipad screen via zoom to the screens in the class room. This allows me to walk around the room and call random students to answer questions, some directly on my ipad.

@Buffy Second year university level.

A bit of encouragement, then let natural selection take its course.

I'm still not sure I understand how precisely this works. Do you write on your iPad while you walk through the classroom? This sounds rather difficult for physiological reasons.

@JochenGlueck Most of things on the slides. So I just need to annotate the slides a bit. I also stop when I need to write something a bit longer.

I was one of those students. Perhaps my perspective is useful: I had previous knowledge which typically covered ~50% of the material taught in most courses. So I'd attend to see what the topics and levels are and when it turned out it was stuff I already know well, I'd work instead (I studied part-time while working). I tried joining just the first few lectures then skipping, but that'd make me miss the point where I needed to start paying attention. I also tried paying attention the first few minutes and then leaving, but that was unacceptable to many professors. Hence, I stayed but worked.

University isn't school. University students are old enough to be responsible for themselves. As long as they don't disturb anyone, just let them do whatever they do. The lecture is a service offered by you/the university to the students, and they have to decide themselves what they make out of it.

Whatever you do, you have an obligation as the instructor not to let them distract students who are interested in following the lecture. YouTube videos are (depending on the seating arrangement) a definite distraction to students sitting behind them.

Maybe figure out WHY those students aren't interested in your lectures and actually try to get them interested. I've had lecturers like you, droning on and on reciting their lecture material (which we all had to buy before the course) and doing nothing else whatsoever during their lectures, including not allowing for questions. Obviously 90% of us just tuned out and did other things, if we shows up at all. When the guy was replaced because he was sick one day his replacement had great engagement.

@jwenting Thanks. But I would not have posted this question if I have been "eciting their lecture material (which we all had to buy before the course) and doing nothing else whatsoever during their lectures, including not allowing for questions".

I think my experience is an unusual one, but not so much that you won't run into it. I have ADHD. When I am learning something new to me but that doesn't require my full attention, I actually find it easier to pay attention if I do something else, like logic puzzles on my phone, at the same time. The additional activity keeps my brain happy, whereas trying to pay full attention to something that isn't engaging enough (even if it is engaging to a degree!) causes me to get lost in boredom. Some of your students might be paying their best attention in a way that looks like distraction!

That said, I rarely did this in university. It comes up more often in my life as an industry worker with meetings and presentations. And I think my experience is the exception, not the rule.

Could you edit and finish the two dangling sentences in your bullet points please? "who are engaged and there to" what? "to answer questions in" what?

Depending on country a lot of the students may be taking the course for some credit requirement and have no actual interest in it.

I've discussed the following elsewhere here. It was CS, but, I think, fundamentally the same.
Many (most?) people have a sort of natural ability in some subjects and it gets them through school to some level. But it ends for nearly all (all?) at some point. Such people have no real need to "learn how to learn". And, seeing something once or twice is all they need to pass the required exams. But then, they hit the wall. Some fail completely at this point and I think that the later they learn the following lessons the harder it is to recover, though I have no experimental evidence of this.
I noticed the same behavior you describe in a class. I asked one of the students why he wasn't taking notes and he pointed to his head, indicating no need. I thought about that for a while and decided that the behavior was self defeating and self limiting, so I spent a class period changing the rules.
Being tenured (and trusted by chair and dean), I first scared them a bit by suggesting that if they weren't really interested in learning the material then we could all agree that they would get F's and could then spend their time elsewhere doing other things that mattered more to them. This caused a bit of a stir in the halls as you would guess, and I don't recommend it for everyone. And a chat with the department head would probably be wise before trying anything like this.
But, I also taught them how to take notes in class and to work to capture the most important messages. I like index cards for big ideas, since they can be carried about for review, shuffled, sorted, combined, extended (if not filled up initially), etc. I bought a big set of cards and handed out a small deck and a rubber band to each student.
For a few weeks, I would end lectures a few minutes early and ask, either specific students or generally, "What is a big idea from today's lecture?", having told them I was expecting up to three such big ideas captured on their index cards. I would agree publicly or not.
I would also start each lecture with the same question-response system. A former teacher (this was math) would start each and every lecture with a five minute quiz based entirely on the previous lecture: "Please take out a sheet of paper...". We hated that guy, but the "stick" was effective even though those quick quizzes were a minor part of the grade.
Learning requires reinforcement and feedback. Few people learn with a single introduction to a big idea. To learn actually requires rewiring the brain (hence repetition/reinforcement). And we sometimes make mistakes in our integration (hence feedback).
See The Art of Changing the Brain by James E Zull for a run-down on the science behind the reinforcement/rewiring/feedback ideas.
See also: Active Learning in general, and how to foster and require it.
Notes: You can't ethically ignore the inactive students. You still have a responsibility for their learning, while still recognizing that some students just won't care or respond.
I'd suggest requiring attendance. If the scale is right, you can also use other active learning ides such as pairing (tripling) students to explore ideas, etc.
If you have a doctorate in math, note that most of your students are not like yourself: driven to learn math. Many students take a few math courses for other purposes and are perfectly satisfied with a modest grade.

I feel a bit ambiguous about requiring attendance. That might get me more students in class who are just doing other things.

My impression is if I ask "Should enforce attendance" here, I will probably be called silly. :'(

I think requiring attendance is kind of a catch-22 situation. It makes most sense in entry level classes where people are not yet used to university life/learn style, but it also will cause the most friction with people. For example I only did my CS studies for the diploma, because you needed to have one to apply to jobs at that time. I had already programmed for almost a decade and if anyone would have forced me to sit into an introduction to Java lecture it would have been a massive waste of time. There were several others in the same situation. We went to the exam and nothing else.

Your second paragraph seems to describe something like a hard wall. Both from personal experience and from people around me I would say this is more often a very gradual increase in difficulty. True, the strategy of simply dozing through class and passibly absorbing the material that worked great in high school was not sufficient in university anymore but a gradual shift of paying more attention and spending more time on the material was sufficient to counter the increasing difficulty.

@OP I would guess those not attending regularly probably fall mostly into two camps: 1. Those who are slacking. 2. Those who can understand the material easily, and will do well in the class regardless. There is the possibility of making attendance optional only for those achieving at least a certain grade (decide on a threshold). There is also the possibility of making attendance optional only for those who have proven themselves by doing some kind of remote learning - but putting together that kind of content is not easy, and details have to be worked out like how to prevent cheating.

Don't require attendance. Track it and show a plot attendance vs grades from the previous year at the start. There will be people with good grades who didn't show up (I was one of them once), but you can point to them (on the chart that is, no actual students involved ;-) and let your students know that unless they are sure that they fall into that category, that showing up was an activity with a good return investment. If there's no correlation, you might have to look at your teaching.

@Marianne013, so, disadvantage this year's group to advantage next year's??? Better run that experiment past the IRB first.

In my undergrad, one lecturer went really far with his attendance records on me (which was typically 10-20% across the board) and sent me an email saying that he was going to go to the Dean of Engineering about it for his class. I replied "I look forward to speaking to him". It never actually happened, nor did his apology when I came top of ~120 students at the end of the semester. He would have looked rather stupid at that point, but he missed the idea that I'd just figured out which books he was using and could go through them in bed at my leisure. Forcing attendance is a terrible idea

"But, I also taught them how to take notes in class and to work to capture the most important messages. I like index cards for big ideas, since they can be carried about for review, shuffled, sorted, combined, extended (if not filled up initially), etc. I bought a big set of cards and handed out a small deck and a rubber band to each student."  This is a failure of the earlier parts of schooling.  By the time students reach university level, they should have already been taught such methods.  Those are the things that people need to learn young - how to learn.

I rejects the idea that taking notes during class is always best for everyone.  Absolutely students benefit from being actively engaged,  and note taking can help, but not for everyone.  For some people,  particularly, but not only,  those with dyslexia or dyspraxia, the act of writing is sufficiently cognitively demanding that it doesn't leave capacity to engage with the material. I do endorse the testing at the start of the next lecture those.  I do with (even without assigning credit), and it works well.

@IanSudbery, please, the question and my answer are about disengagement,

@Marianne013 I've done that before, showing them clear positive correlation with attendance and exam grades (which of course does not imply causality), but there seemed to be little effect on participation.

Most of this answer (the back 2/3rds) is about theory of learning and note-taking. Only the 1st part is about disengaged students. I think the intent is to add "how to study" tips in class and the disengaged students will pay more attention? The book recommendations seem unrelated. Are those are to help lecturers wishing to add "how to study" tips? Or do they just back-up what you already wrote about note-taking?

@OwenReynolds, the idea is to drive active learning. The notes force evaluation as do my questions

It is appropriate to expect active participation in class by several methods, eg, questions and presentations that have been prepared. I dit n't like doing frequent short qi uizzes but I found it was the only way to insure students read the assigned material. I gave students the chance to ask any questions they wanted and only gave a quiz if the questions ran out early.

I cannot even describe how much I would have hated this as a student, and if forced into it I would have failed utterly.  I suspect that this kind of action might help some students, but for students that that type of learning doesn't work for (or for whom it might work acceptably well for, but who are unwilling to try it for whatever reason) this is just weeding them out when they might otherwise do well.

If the idea is to drive active learning, I wonder if this might benefit from stating that at the beginning: "At the start of each course I devote some time to explaining Active Learning -- how to take notes. I've even handed out notecards to students". Otherwise this looks like a transcript of you thinking out loud until arriving at your real reply.

@Beska So, which practice suggested in this answer do you dislike? Taking notes? Quizzes?

@Timmy Enforcing a specific process for learning (like the notecards) is part of it, but the piece that jumped out immediately to me was "For a few weeks, I would end lectures a few minutes early and ask, either specific students or generally, 'What is a big idea from today's lecture?', having told them I was expecting up to three such big ideas captured on their index cards. I would agree publicly or not."  For anyone with social anxiety, this is pretty much a guarantee that the student will shut down and/or avoid/drop the class.

@Beska Thanks for the clarification. I don't understand how anyone could avoid that. Of course, the professor will ask questions and publicly agree or disagree with the answers. I don't see how anyone can complete a college education without ever being asked to answer questions.

I've done fine with your option #1 -- not doing anything (*). One reason is that we don't know why they aren't paying attention, and those reasons are different. Some know the basics and are waiting for the harder stuff. Some need the class to be considered full-time but plan to actually pass it next semester. And so on. But the main reason to do nothing is that there are always more productive things I could be doing: thinking about how to add common student Q's to the lecture for next semester, writing new assignments, new test questions, checking whether I need to slow down or review, writing up plagiarism ... . There's only so much time and worrying about a few people who aren't asking for help and who know my office hours if they do is at the far end of the effort vs. results curve.
(*) Well, I do one thing about not-paying-attention students. In my first day lecture I say "it's fine to show up and just keep an ear open while you do something else, but try not to distract other people, so sit near the back or sides". Which means the other thing I do is to treat them like normal students. No glaring or snide remarks. I want them to know that if they finally engage, I won't embarrass them.

My general feeling on this follows three stages:

Is there a reason that they are not engaging, that we might be able to solve together? There might be accessibility needs, or they might be struggling, perhaps missed some early material, and have given up. So it's worth reaching out. If numbers permit it may be worth a private conversation, or there might be a personal tutor or similar role who can do this.

Are they disturbing others and impacting their learning? (e.g., youtube videos might have this effect if not in the back row) If so, you have to stomp on this.

At the end of the day they are adults, and if they want to spend huge amounts of money and time to be there and then not pay attention, that is up to them. If there's no underlying issue (or there is and they have rejected attempts to help), and it isn't bothering anybody else... at some point it isn't your problem any more.



Your second point is so important, if they are annoying or distracting, this will have a negative impact on the motivation of other students.

One of my sister's undergrad math professors had a rather unorthodox and creative method of encouraging student engagement: He announced in class orientation that each lecture would contain one intentional lie, and they should be alert to spot it.
In the first few lectures, the lie was something obvious, and the students immediately called it out. The professor congratulated them for getting it right, and moved on with the lecture.
As the semester went on, the lies got more subtle, and increasingly often they would reach the end of the lecture with no one having spotted the lie. Whenever this happened, the students were tasked with figuring out the lie using their notes, and the next lecture began with a discussion of what the missed lie had been.
Then, late in the semester, there came a lecture where no one in the class could identify the lie, despite many hours spent scouring their notes for discrepancies or anything that wasn't properly supported by its explanation. At the beginning of the next lecture, the professor revealed that there was no lie in that lecture. The statement in orientation that every lecture would contain a lie had, itself, been the orientation lecture's lie. That particular lecture was chosen to be the singular lie-free lecture because it covered the most difficult and important topic in the course, and getting the students to put in lots of effort searching for a lie in it that wasn't there resulted in them learning the material of that lecture very thoroughly.
I think the elements of this method that made it so effective are that it made the class more interactive, in a fun sort-of-game-like way, that required strong comprehension of the material to engage with. Giving the students a regular opportunity to call out their teacher likely also added to its appeal for the students.

I can see how this would work for a lot of students but I would be extremely annoyed as a student to find out about the lecture which didn't have a lie in it. I'm autistic and find being lied to really distressing - I'd be able to cope with the "one lie per lecture" thing but looking for a lie when there wasn't one would be too far for me.

@deee Would it help for you if the existence of that lecture were also announced up front, along with the reason for not identifying it in advance?

@deee , I hope this question is not insensitive, as I am genuinely curious: Would my autistic students find such false statements distressing? Presumably, these statements are false claims about mathematics.

@Timmy Yes, the lies were all false statements about mathematics. The whole point of them was to motivate the students to think about what they were learning and evaluate whether it made sense, thereby improving their understanding of the class. As a knowledgeable but non-expert third party to your question, I think most autistic students would be fine with it as long as they're told in advance and understand the purpose of it, but a few might still be distressed.

@Timmy Autism makes subjective nuances hard to judge, implicit social conventions hard to deduce by observation, and ambiguous interactions hard to resolve. Autistic people tend to develop a system of rules to navigate social interaction, and lies undermine that by throwing the hardest kinds of problems for them into everything. Lies in a restricted scope, with a positive purpose, with forewarning, and identifiable by clear-cut mathematical reasoning, avoid the main reasons for distress. Some autistic people may nonetheless be unable to fully accept an exception to their "lies are bad" rule.

@Timmy Side note, often one of the kindest and most helpful things you can do for an autistic person is to give them a clear and explicit explanation of a social convention they did not yet understand. Even, or especially, simple things that seem blatantly obvious to you. The "blatantly obvious" ones can actually be the most helpful to explain, because autism makes many of them actually not obvious at all, and at the same time their obviousness to most people makes people not even consider explaining them, due to assuming that they must be already known and understood.

Interesting idea. Perhaps it would be better to call it an "inaccuracy" than a "lie."

@Douglas For me, yes, knowing that one lecture didn't have a lie would make it a lot better. The part I would find distressing is feeling like the rules as stated had changed under me. J.R's suggestion of framing it as an "inaccuracy" is also good.

I think the difference for me is between "false statements about mathematics" as you put it, compared to "false statements about how the course works".

Your suggestion labeled #2 is an interesting one:

Be more direct and ask them to answer questions in class.

It's worth asking yourself, "How am I motivating my students to pay more attention in class?" If you tend to lecture for 50 minutes straight without ever asking them to contribute, and then you post your lecture notes online after class, then your easily-distracted students are more likely to get easily distracted.
I don't think you'll ever eliminate this problem completely, but a more Socratic approach when you strategically call on students to do some talking can go a long way into increasing attentiveness, particular if students notice that watching YouTube videos makes them more likely to be called on.
That said, I'd advise against calling on students simply as a punitive measure for not paying attention. Instead, ask yourself how you can make your time in the class more interactive and engaging for all students.

This is a partial answer, to complement the other ones here.
As someone who's been on his laptop and even slept during classes he absolutely loved (and also taken intense notes in other classes) and who turned out just fine academically:
Your first step (after ensuring they aren't being disruptive) should be to observe how those students are doing academically. If they're doing fine, let them be. Doing anything else will do nothing other than embarrass them and achieve absolutely nothing positive; in fact, it might make them resent you or skip lecture entirely.
You have to realize, some people are just stronger in some classes. Maybe the material comes naturally to them, maybe they already have a lot of background in that area, or maybe they've looked at the lectures ahead of time... there are a million reasons not everyone will need an equal amount of attention to the same material you're teaching at that point in time.
Your job is to teach, not to make sure people are paying attention. If you find that they're not learning adequately, then your second step should be to figure out how to handle that -- and, for that, I defer to the other answers.
But please don't skip the step of figuring out "is there an actual problem here to solve". Don't solve what's not broken; you'll only make it worse.

As others have pointed out, there can be good reasons to pay only a bit attention like they already know the general topic but don't want to miss when something new comes up.
It can be very boring when you are taught to something which you already know.
As long as they don't affect other students I see no problem in ignoring them.
There is one point to consider:
A university usually has some better places where you can watch a YouTube video than a class room with a lecturing teacher. They have a reason to be in your class room.
If you get the chance, kindly ask them in person after the class why they attend your class.
You may get confirmation with the prospect that they will pay more attention on the next upcomming topic.
If they don't have a reason and just sit through the hour then they may think twice before they do this again.
A casual talk may be less intimidating than when you invite them to office ours.
